# Cypress comparing values

Tags: cypress

I want to test an ordering, I want to compare a number of add-to-cart fields with a shopping cart.
This is a webpage - https://demo.nopcommerce.com/build-your-own-computer

```
    let numOfNotifications
    cy.get('.cart-qty').then((value) => {
        numOfNotifications = value[0].innerText
    }).then(() => {
        cy.get('#product_enteredQuantity_1').clear().type(4)
        cy.get('#add-to-cart-button-1').click().then((items => {
            expect(items.length).to.be.eq(Number(numOfNotifications))
        }))
    })
```

I expected them to be eq after the test was passed but I got an error - 1 to equal NaN

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asBuI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The "NaN" in the error message means "not a number".

The error occurs because `numOfNotifications = value[0].innerText` gives you text, which is not a number.

You could fix it with `numOfNotifications = parseInt(value[0].innerText)`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, wit this solution I still have the same error message. :D

Comment: I just noticed `.to.be.eq(Number(numOfNotifications))` -  maybe also change that to `.to.be.eq(numOfNotifications)`. Not sure that `Number()` does a conversion.

Comment: Looking up [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) - from the examples it should work for you. Maybe it's a problem with the ChaiJs `expect()` library.